# How to set up Let's Encrypt for a Go server application

Tags: ssl, go, https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

I have my own domain with web services written in Go. I am using the inbuilt Go web server, without Nginx or Apache in front.

I would like to start serving over HTTPS and I realized Let's Encrypt is just about to become THE WAY for doing that.

Can anyone share the whole setup procedure for configuring a Go app running on a Linux server?

Comment: Use https://caddyserver.com/ - which does this for you (issues a certificate & proxies to your application).

Comment: What is the question : how to create a certificate for a Go webserver ? How to configure the Go webserver to use the certificate/private key ? Other ?

Comment: Go's own `crypto/tls` package is able to load certificates (public and private keys) from PEM-formatted files. A tool provided by Let's Encrypt (now it appears to be rather promoted by EFF) is able to provide you with that PEM-formatted file. So: 1) Read a guide on obtaining the certificate from Let's Encrypt and do that; 2) Once you have that certificate, read up on how to make `crypto/tls` read it and implement that in your servers; 3) Have your servers read your cert. You're done.

Comment: To say that in other way, there's no way of "configuring" your servers unless you already *implemented* configuration knobs in them to do that. Since you most probably have not yet, you might do something like making them parse a special command-line option specifying the pathname of the certificate, say, `-cert`.

Comment: **Related info**: redirecting all http traffic to https. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536006/how-do-i-rewrite-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-go

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This is the minimal automatic setup of an HTTPS server using Go and Let's Encrypt certificates I have found:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert"
)

func main() {
    certManager := autocert.Manager{
        Prompt:     autocert.AcceptTOS,
        HostPolicy: autocert.HostWhitelist("example.com"), //Your domain here
        Cache:      autocert.DirCache("certs"),            //Folder for storing certificates
    }

    http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Write([]byte("Hello world"))
    })

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr: ":https",
        TLSConfig: &tls.Config{
            GetCertificate: certManager.GetCertificate,
            MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12, // improves cert reputation score at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/
        },
    }

    go http.ListenAndServe(":http", certManager.HTTPHandler(nil))

    log.Fatal(server.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")) //Key and cert are coming from Let's Encrypt
}
```

More information on the autocert package: [link](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert)

EDIT: Needed to make http available because of [letsencrypt security issue](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/important-what-you-need-to-know-about-tls-sni-validation-issues/50811), read more [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/21890). As a bonus of this fix we now have http-->https redirect. The old example will continue to work if you have already received certificates on it, but it will break for new sites.

Comment: Thanks, it is the example I was looking for! But one hast to be careful according to the documentation: *This package is a work in progress and makes no API stability promises.*

Comment: Thank you very much!
This really should be selected as the correct answer.

Comment: This does not include the .well-known folder, does it? So this snippet only includes using the certificates, not renewing them?

Comment: No this is the complete package. If you run this code you'll see that it creates a valid certificate. And since it can create it can also update. The server I'm running this on has updated the certificate at least once.

Comment: @JamesCameron It uses the TLS-SNI challenge to provision the certificate not the HTTP.

Comment: I get those two handshake errors and I can't figure out what the problem is: 
"acme/autocert: missing server name" and "acme/autocert: host not configured". Can someone help me please?

Comment: @MarcoM Create a new stackoverflow question where you paste your code and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: @Pylinux Question created: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43161559/setting-up-lets-encrypt-with-go-handshake-errors

Comment: There is no such method certManager.HTTPHandler(nil)

Comment: @Pushan What version of `golang.org/x/crypto/acme/autocert` are you using? Because in master it seems like the function is there: [link](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/acme/autocert/autocert_test.go#L672)

Comment: Why doesn't this need an LE account?

Answer (score 37):

I found a very simple solution, using the **standalone** mode.

**INSTALL THE CERTBOT CLIENT** (recommended by Let's Encrypt)

```
(go to the directory where you want to install the certbot client)
git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot
cd certbot
./certbot-auto --help`
```

**ISSUE CERTIFICATE (FIRST TIME)**

N.B. this operation happens through the port 80, so in case your Go app listens on port 80, it needs to be switched off before running this command (which is very quick to run, by the way)

`./certbot-auto certonly --standalone-supported-challenges http-01 -d www.yourdomain.com`

**ADD SSL LISTENER IN YOUR GO CODE**

`http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yourdomain.com/fullchain.pem", "/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.yourdomain.com/privkey.pem", nil)`

## Done!

**TO RENEW CERTIFICATE** (certificates expire after 90 days)

N.B. You can either run this manually (you will receive an email several days before the certificate expires), or set up a crontab

if your Go app doesn't listen to port 80 anymore, your Go app can keep running while you execute this command:
`./certbot-auto renew --standalone`

if your Go app still listens to port 80, you can specify the commands to stop and restart the Go app:
`./certbot-auto renew --standalone --pre-hook "command to stop Go app" --post-hook "command to start Go app"`

for the complete documentation of the Certbot commands:
https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html

Comment: I got this working too, but used the `dns` challenge method where you add a TXT record to your dns.

Comment: what about permissions issue regarding cert and permkey files?
You do not run your golang server/app as root but those files are owned by root.

Comment: How to reload pem files without restarting the server when certbot update?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use DNS verification, that's the way to go for renewals.

For using the certificate, simple do:

```
    c := &tls.Config{MinVersion: tls.VersionTLS12}
    s := &http.Server{Addr: ":443", Handler: Gzipler(nosurf.New(router), 1), TLSConfig: c}
    log.Fatal(s.ListenAndServeTLS(
        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/fullchain.pem", 
        "/etc/letsencrypt/live/XXX/privkey.pem"
    ))
```

This one has Gzip & CSRF protection included. You can use

```
Handler: router
```

without those extra features.