# Does redirect from HTTP to HTTPS have encryption?

Tags: ssl, go, https

I have an HTTPS server in Go, so that users can enter https://example.com in their browser. I'd like them to also be able to type in "example.com" to reach my HTTPS server. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37536006/how-do-i-rewrite-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-go) I see that the standard solution is to run an HTTP server that redirects to https://example.com.

I'm wondering if this is as secure as if everything were in HTTPS. In particular, if a user sends a POST request to "example.com", will the content be encrypted while it passes through the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A POST request to an HTTP server is not secure. This includes the case where the server responds to the POST with a redirect to an HTTPS server.

Browsers automatically follow redirects. The request to the HTTPS server is secure.

Comment: Then how come if I type in "example.com" for well known sites, Chrome displays the green "Secure" logo because of the HTTPS redirect? What exactly is secured if the only request I made was over an insecure HTTP connection?

Comment: @rampatowl, see also [HSTS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Strict-Transport-Security), the Preload section in particular. This can prevent the redirect from happening in the first place.